# MySQL SELECT Key Value table as row

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following MySQL table "**application_session**" with the following columns:

```
 - applicationId
 - applicationKey
 - applicationVal
 - applicationDate
```

This table has many key/value pairs in it, keys and vals can change, new pairs can be added or removed. Furthermore, every "**applicationId**" can have different key/value pairs from others.

What's the best way to dynamically return (SELECT query) all pairs in a rows where "**applicationKey**" is the column name and "**applicationVal**" the result?

I hope I'm explaining things right.

Comment: You want a query that returns the rows in which the `applicationKey` is equal to the `applicationVal`, or you want them all seriallized, or you want to compare them to the `applicationId`, or something else? I can't follow, please elaborate.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: I like the way you say "help *and* attention" :>  A way to tame your audience.

Comment: @Mureinik : Thanks for your prompt response. Please go to [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7vacr6sm/) to see what I mean.